# HTML/CSS: a:hover doesn't seem to change other div?

Tags: css, html

I might have overseen a really stupid mistake, but I can't find out why this doesn't work:

Here's my HTML, it's a simple menu, and if I hover "Home" or "Play" the font-color of the div "deco" changes to red...

```
<div class="menu">
<h1>
    <a href="#">HOME</a> <a href="#">PLAY</a> <a href="#">LOGIN</a>
     <div id="deco">A</div>
</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
height:100%;
width:100%;
display: block;
background-color: #000;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

.menu {

margin-top:10%;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
text-align: center;
}

h1 { 
font-family: "Dauphin";
color: #FFFFFF;
} 

a {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;  
}


a:hover #deco{
color: red;
}

#deco {
font-family: "Invader";
top: 123px;
color: #FFF;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector doesn't match the element. For `a:hover #deco` to work, the div has to live inside the anchor like so:

```
<a href="#">HOME
     <div id="deco">A</div>
</a>
```

Modern browsers support the general sibling selector ~:

```
a:hover ~ #deco
```

If you need to support browsers that do not support the general sibling selector, you can achieve this with jQuery something like this:

```
$('a').hover(
    function() { $('#deco').addClass('link-hover'); }, 
    function() { $('#deco').removeClass('link-hover'); });
```

And define the CSS:

```
#deco.link-hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yeah I totally didn't see that... Maybe I should take a break! Anyways thanks for this fantastic answer it's totally correct!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because `#deco` isn't a child element of the `a` tag.

The CSS declaration `a:hover #deco` refers to any element with ID 'deco' that is a child (e.g. contained inside of) an anchor element that is in the hover state.

For it to work you need #deco to be inside of the A tag, a child rather than a sibling element.  Or you could leave the HTML as-is and accomplish this with simple jQuery instead (using .css or .addClass to change the style definition on hover).